# nodejs s3.getHeadObject() throws BadRequest Error with no errorMessage

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am running a nodejs-express application in aws-serverless. this application is triggered when one of my buckets retrieves a new file. Inside my code logic, there is a step where I need to retrieve headObj of the uploaded file in s3 bucket.

```
// s3
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
AWS.config.update({region: 'eur-central-1'});
const s3Bucket : AWS.S3 = new AWS.S3([S3_CONFIG]);

...
const headObj = await s3Bucket.headObject(getOptions).promise();
...
```

this somehow throws me the following error

```
{
    "errorMessage": null,
    "errorType": "BadRequest",
    "stackTrace": [.....]
}
```

I ran the same application before in another environment (development). But since Im running this in production It didnt seem to work for me.

aws-sdk version : 2.48
nodejs version : 8.xx

Answer (score 0):

I have used the transfer acceleration, therefore I has to activate the option in my bucket settings. But still, I don't understand why there is no error message.